# Start Unix screen, Run command, Detach

Tags: ubuntu, bash, gnu-screen

How can `screen` be used to start a new session and run a command within that session without killing that session?

```
 screen -S myScreenName runSomething
```

I tried the above command and it says

```
[screen is terminating]
```

Did it run the command then kill the screen? I would like the screen to be detached after running the command instead of killing it. How can that be done?

Comment: Why are you using screen here at all, if the command is just going to exit immediately?

Comment: @MichaelHampton the command doesn't exit immediately, it runs a daemon that prints to stdout, so I would like to keep it in a screen session. I will be starting the screen session from an Ansible playbook. I don't know why screen terminates when I ran that command.

Comment: Then tell the daemon not to daemonize.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Great that works. Can screen be asked to detach after running the command? Tried `-d` but it says `There is no screen to be detached matching myScreenName`

Answer (score 30):

This script prevent session killing:

```
screen -dmS test bash -c 'echo waiting 5 senconds...; sleep 5; exec bash'
```

Regards!

Comment: It seems that starting a session name with `.` is not allowed (tried to give a relative file path as both session name and one of the arguments).

Answer (score 11):

to run a command and detach from the session:

```
screen -d -m runSomething
```

Comment: The screen still terminates when using this command.

Answer (score 5):

If you keep forgetting the right letters that go after dash, in order to avoid revisiting this question, you might as well type:

```
screen -h
```

where you'll see:

```
-dmS name     Start as daemon: Screen session in detached mode.
```